# Why my RegEx doesn't replace multiple occurrences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove the "[[" and "]]" from my string with regex in JavaSript (I know it can easily be done with simple replace, but that is not what I want)

```
var str = "abc [[def]] ghi [[jkl]] mno";
str = str.replace(/\[\[(.*)\]\]/g, "$1");
```

the resulting string is `abc def]] ghi [[jkl mno`instead of `abc def ghi jkl mno` What can I do?

Comment: Use a non-greedy version: `/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RegEx,

```
/\[\[(.*)\]\]/
```

actually says, start from `[[`, *match as many characters as possible* (because of the `*`), till you see `]]`. So it actually matches the string,

```
[[def]] ghi [[jkl]]
```

and replace it with the matched characters between `[[` and `]]` which is `def]] ghi [[jkl`, since it is the maximum possible match. That is why you are getting,

```
abc def]] ghi [[jkl mno
```

as the result. To fix this, you need to make the `*`, non-greedy like this

```
str = str.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, "$1");
```

Now, the `?` makes `*` match *as minimum as* possible. So, it first matches,  `[[def]]` and replaces it with `def` then it matches `[[jkl]]` and replaces it with `jkl`.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, "$1");
```

Make your `*` non greedy.or

```
[\[\]]+
```

Simple replace this by `empty string`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply try this also,

```
> var str = "abc [[def]] ghi [[jkl]] mno";
> str.replace(/\[\[|\]\]/g, "")
'abc def ghi jkl mno'
```

The above regex would match `[[` or `]]` symbols. Replacing those matched characters with empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simpler:

```
str = str.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "");
```

```js
var str = "abc [[def]] ghi [[jkl]] mno";
str = str.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "");
alert( str )
```